# Difference between thread.join and thread.abort in python multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading

I am new to python multi threading and trying to understand the basic difference between joining multiple worker threads and calling abort on them after I am done processing with them. Can somebody please explain me with an example?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "abort"? (There is no such concept in *at least* Python's ``multithreading.Thread`` API).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have implemented an abort API which sets __abort flag to true for the class and calls notify() to notify the other threads that its done. So, whats the internal implementation of join() in python like?

Comment: ``.join()`` just waits for the threads to finish. It's blocking unless you specify a timeout. It doesn't terminate the threads at all.

Comment: yeah, i understood the concept, thanks :)

Comment: If you understand the concept; then why the question? :) Haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.join() and setting a abort flags are two different steps in cleanly shutting down a thread.

join() just waits for a thread that is going to terminate anyway to be finished. Thus:

```
import threading
import time

def thread_main():
    time.sleep(10)
t = threading.Thread(target=thread_main)
t.start()
t.join()
```

This is a reasonable program. The join just waits until the thread is finished. It doesn't do anything to make that happen, but the thread will terminate anyway, because it is just a 10 second sleep.

In contrast

```
import threading
import time

def thread_main():
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
t = threading.Thread(target=thread_main)
t.start()
t.join()
```

Is not a good idea, because join will still wait for the thread to terminate on it's own. But the thread will never do that because it loops forever. Thus the whole program can't terminate.

That's the point where you want some kind of signaling to the thread for it so stop itself

```
import threading
import time

stop_thread = False

def thread_main():
    while not stop_thread:
        time.sleep(10)
t = threading.Thread(target=thread_main)
t.start()

stop_thread = True

t.join()
```

Here stop_thread takes the role of your __abort flag and signals the thread to stop after it has finished with it's latest work (the sleep(10) in this case)

Thus this program again is reasonable and terminates when asked to do.

Another popular way to signal a thread to stop when the thread uses a consumer pattern (i.e. gets its work from a queue) is to post a special 'terminate now' work item as alternative to setting a flag variable:

```
def thread_main():
    while True:
        (quit, data) = work_queue().get()
        if quit: break
        do_work(data)
```